# Why is nHibernate lazy loading and ignoring the results of a future query?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have a method that retrieves an Entity from a database using nHibernate. It's quite a complex Entity:

*Level4 has many Level3s which have many Level2s which have many Level1s which has a Level1Ref*

So I use a few futures like this:

```
        var future = this.Session.QueryOver<Level4>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == level4Id)
            .Fetch(x => x.Level3List).Eager
            .Fetch(x => x.Level3List.First().Level2List).Eager
            .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Level3List, () => level3Alias, x => x.AnotherThing.Id == anotherThingId)
            .FutureValue();
```

And some queries like this:

```
        this.Session.QueryOver<Level1>()
            .Fetch(x => x).Eager
            .Fetch(x => x.Level1Ref).Eager
            .Fetch(x => x.Level2).Eager
            .Inner.JoinAlias(x => x.Level2, () => level2Alias)
            .Inner.JoinAlias(() => level2Alias.Level3, () => level3Alias, x => x.AnotherThing.Id == anotherThingId && level3Alias.Level4.Id == level4Id)
            .Future();
```

And then:

```
var record = future.Value;
```

This all generates the SQL that I would expect but when I try to iterate over the Level2.Level1List it lazy loads the records in that list.

**The Question:**

This is the problem. What have I? done wrong in my query that nHibernate thinks it needs to go to the database for information that it has already got? (I've got a hunch that I need to swap some of my JoinQueryOver bits for eager fetches?

(Questions edited to simplify examples)

Comment: I think your hunch is right. `Future` is for deferring execution of (usually) a batch of queries so that there's only one round trip to the database. `Fetch` is probably what you're after-- it can load associated entities together. That said, in my experience it gets buggy for more than 2 levels of fetching.

Comment: In my experience, NHibernate is not very strong at eager fetching. I usually rely on lazy-loading, which can perform really well if properly [set up](/a/36070727/1178314).

Comment: Thanks @Frédéric The goal for us is to hit the database as few times as possible so lazy-loading is not what we're after.

Comment: A properly set-up lazy-loading may allow you to have, in your case, only 5 calls to db (one per entity type). For reducing them more, you may combine futures and eager loadings as you are trying. For investigating what gets wrong, have you checked your first `futur.Value` has its dependencies actually eager loaded as expected? I do not use the `QueryOver` API, but it does look to me your first queries only joins "aimlessly" without fetching. Joining is  for applying additional filter criteria by example. Fetching is another additional beast usually (at least, it is the case with HQL).

Comment: Thanks @Frédéric The SQL is generated as I would expect but Future.Value does not have its dependencies loaded as I would expect (closing the nHibernate session and carrying on with my code results in a failed to lazily initialize a collection of role error) so I came to the same conclusion as you did. I've been tinkering with my queries and you can see my latest attempt in the edit above but it still does not work.

Comment: At that point, as I am not using `QueryOver` and am not willing to investigate it, it is hard for me to help you more. You may check if removing the future change anything to your fetching problem with the first query. Then, you may have better asking a new question specifically for this first query if you can not get it working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of investigation the only way I could get this working was change all of my queries so they have the same TRoot. Ie. Change them so they all start like this:

```
this.Session.QueryOver<Level4>()
```

This obviously isn't ideal in situations like this:

> FishMonger
>
> > Collection of Fish
> >
> > > Collection of Eye
> > >       Collection of Bone

It means I have to write two queries and join in Fish twice...

The alternative is to lazy load and batch the queries but the requirement is to make only one round trip to the database.